# Finding how many of a certain character in each element in a list

Tags: python, list, character, element

I want to find how many `' '`(whitespaces) there are in each of these sentences which happen to be elements in a list. So, for:
`['this is a sentence', 'this is one more sentence']`
Calling element 0 would return a value of 3, and calling element 1 would return a value of 4. I really am having trouble doing both of finding the whitespaces as well as looping through every element to find the one with the highest number of whitespaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a simple list-coprehension using [`count`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.count)

```
>>> lst = ['this is a sentence', 'this is one more sentence']
>>> [i.count(' ') for i in lst]
[3, 4]
```

Other ways include using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map)

```
>>> map(lambda x:x.count(' '),lst)
[3, 4]
```

---

If you want a callable (which is a function that iterates through your list as you have mentioned)  it can be implemented as

```
>>> def countspace(x):
...     return x.count(' ')
...
```

and executed as

```
>>> for i in lst:
...     print countspace(i)
... 
3
4
```

---

This can be solved using regexes using the [`re` module](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html) as mentioned below by [Grijesh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29394347/python-finding-how-many-of-a-certain-character-in-each-element-in-a-list/29394376#comment46965409_29394376)

```
>>> import re
>>> [len(re.findall(r"\s", i)) for i in lst]
[3, 4]
```

---

**Post edit**

As you say you need to find the max element also, you can do

```
>>> vals = [i.count(' ') for i in lst] 
>>> lst[vals.index(max(vals))]
'this is one more sentence'
```

This can be implemented as a callable using

```
>>> def getmax(lst):
...     vals = [i.count(' ') for i in lst]
...     maxel = lst[vals.index(max(vals))]
...     return (vals,maxel)
```

and use it as

```
>>> getmax(lst)
([3, 4], 'this is one more sentence')
```

---

**Post comment edit**

```
>>> s = 'this is a sentence. this is one more sentence'
>>> lst = s.split('. ')
>>> [i.count(' ') for i in lst]
[3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

You state "whitespace", normally that would include these characters `'\t\n\x0b\x0c\r '`, plus any unicode characters, e.g. u'\u3000' (IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE).

A regex solution is one of the better ones, because it easily supports any unicode whitespace codepoint in addition to the usual ascii ones. Just use [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) and set the [`re.UNICODE`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.UNICODE) flag:

```
import re

def count_whitespace(s):
    return len(re.findall(r'\s', s, re.UNICODE))

l = ['this is a sentence',
     'this is one more sentence',
     '',
     u'\u3000\u2029    abcd\t\tefghi\0xb  \n\r\nj k  l\tm    \n\n',
     'nowhitespaceinthisstring']

for s in l:
    print count_whitespace(s)
```

**Output**

```
3
4
0
23
0
```

---

An easy, non-regex, way to do this is with `str.split()` which naturally splits on any whitespace character and is an effective way of removing all whitespace from a string. This also works with unicode whitespace characters:

```
def count_whitespace(s):
    return len(s) - len(''.join(s.split()))

for s in l:
    print count_whitespace(s)
```

**Output**

```
3
4
0
23
0
```

---

Finally, picking out the sentence with the most whitespace characters:

```
>>> max((count_whitespace(s), s) for s in l)[1]
u'\u3000\u2029    abcd\t\tefghi\x00xb  \n\r\nj k  l\tm    \n\n'
```

Comment: You could have added links to the modules so that the OP could learn

Comment: @BhargavRao: maybe... `re` is the only external module mentioned and the doco is not difficult to find. I've added a reference to `re.findall()` just in case :)

Comment: Good one bro! Always links to the docs are the best help which we can provide :)

Comment: @BhargavRao:   Yes sir! :S

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html).I dont know whether it is time consuming than `.count()`

```
from collections import Counter
lst = ['this is a sentence', 'this is one more sentence']
>>>[Counter(i)[' '] for i in lst]
[3, 4]
```

Comment: You could have added links to the modules so that the OP could learn

Comment: @BhargavRao updated :), also i am your fan in stack :)

Comment: You are great in Python, Thats why :)

Comment: Thanks bro. I'm still an amateur though :)